# "TypeError: $(...) is null" What's Going On?

Tags: javascript, firebug, typeerror

Firebug is giving the error:

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
$('#menu img').hover(
```

I have no idea why. The seemingly problematic script is this which replaces an image when the cursor hovers over an image:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var storeNormalPath;
    $('#menu img').hover(
        function()
        {   
            storeNormalPath = $(this).attr('src');
            var imgArray = $(this).attr('src').split('.jpg');
            $(this).attr('src', imgArray[0]+'Hover.jpg');
        }, 
        function() 
        {   
            $(this).attr('src', storeNormalPath);
        }
        ).click (function()
        {
            //empty now
        });
});
```

Comment: if the answer of dayala solved your problem, then you should marked as the "Accepted answer"..... I recommend you to read the [faq] (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to be more familiar with Stack Overflow.... Welcome! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some looking over your page using chrome's console, it looks that even `$(document)` is returning null.
`jQuery(document)` however, works, which suggests there is something in conflict with jQuery's $ operator.

(*Source*: I would direct you to this question: [$.document is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945310/document-is-null))

Seeing that you have both **jquery-1.5.1.min.js** AND **jquery.1.4.2.js** referenced in your page header, perhaps that could be the reason of the conflict? Have you tried loading only one of them?

Let us know if that helps, sorry I couldn't be more help.
Good luck!

Comment: Just removed both of them and using 1.9.1. Same error occurs. This is the only jquery file and it's called first before any jquery.

Comment: well, replacing all $(element) jQuery(element) should work, but ideally one would find the origin of the conflict.

I took a final look at your scripts, and perhaps in calscript.js first function "function $(element)" lies the culprit? have you tried commenting out that function?
Of course that is only if you want to use jQuery $(element) shorthand notation.

source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058463/what-is-jquerydocument-vs-document